# How to get Outlook to show a total count of recipients?

Tags: exchange, microsoft-outlook-2013

Outlook displays a warning of y contact groups contain over z recipients. Only some contact groups are included in this. Is there way to make it show the total number of recipients of a message? This is all happening with an Exchange Server.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're asking about the MailTips that display when an email is being composed to a large audience.

The MailTips rely on what's called Group Metrics. Assuming that Group Metrics are enabled (and since you mention contacts, you might need to enable it for external recipients as well, which is disabled by default)...

```
[PS] C:\>Get-OrganizationConfig | fl MailTips*


MailTipsAllTipsEnabled                : True
MailTipsExternalRecipientsTipsEnabled : False
MailTipsGroupMetricsEnabled           : True
MailTipsLargeAudienceThreshold        : 25
MailTipsMailboxSourcedTipsEnabled     : True
```

...the Exchange server calculates the number of members in a group and stamps it on an attribute called msExchGroupMemberCount and msExchGroupExternalMemberCount. Exchange 2010 does this on a schedule, while Exchange 2013/2016 do it as a continual background process that stops if server load is too high. Until the Group Metrics have been calculated, MailTips can't warn you about sending to a large audience. So it's possible that either

- your Group Metrics are disabled
- Group Metrics are not yet calculated
- for those groups Group Metrics are calculated, but the server or client-side cache hasn't updated yet